# Filter Sharepoint 2013 Search user from results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have a farm with a two way trust with between DomainA and DomainB.
I have Search service and User profile configured.

In the people search results I have users from both the domains i.e.
domainA\user1
DomainB\user1

How do I filter the results.

I checked result sources but did not find a way to filter the first domain.

Is there any way to filter the DomainA\user1 from the results

Answer (score 1):

1) Navigate to search result page then switch page into edit mode

2) Click on edit properties of people search result webpart

3) Click on change Query then make changes same as below and replace with your domain (DomainA) where I marked.

[image]

Comment: I tried this approach but then it only shows the results with the account name like 'domain . The local search is blank.

Comment: which scope you were updated?